# Jquery: Calculate real time form input which also changes with checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, checkbox

I have a form where I need to calculate GST (Goods Services Tax) real time inline on the form

> (GST = Price/11)

which I have managed to do with the following script. 
But it also needs to be changed if I click on

> checkbox (exc. GST) means GST = 10% of the price

and

> checkbox (GST Free) means GST = 0

HTML Form:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" name="newItemForm" id="newItemForm" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="itemName" id="itemName" style="text-transform:capitalize" placeholder="Enter Item Name" autocomplete="off">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="price" id="price" placeholder="Item Price" onkeyup="calculateGST()" autocomplete="off"> 
              </div>
              <div>
                <label class="checkbox-inlibe">
                  <input type="checkbox" Value="incGST"> Exc. GST
                </label>
                <label class="checkbox-inlibe">
                  <input type="checkbox" Value="FRE"> GST Free
                </label>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control calGST" name="gst" id="gst" placeholder="GST" autocomplete="off" disabled>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="number" class="form-control" name="unitsPerCTN" id="unitsPerCTN" value="" placeholder="Units Per CRT" autocomplete="off">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="supplier" id="supplier" style="text-transform:capitalize" placeholder="Supplier" autocomplete="off">
              </div>
              <button type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </form>
```

SCRIPT:

```
<script>
function calculateGST() {
    var priceStr =document.newItemForm.price.value;
    if (!priceStr)
        priceStr = '0';
    var price = parseFloat(priceStr);
    document.newItemForm.gst.value = price / 11;
}
</script>
```

**note: jquery is also added on this page. **

Comment: is this a demo or a question>?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily accomplish this by using event listeners. Since you tagged jQuery, you can use the [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method.

Example:

```
$('form checkbox').on('change', function(evt) {
    if( $(this).is(':checked') ) {
        //checked
    }else {
        //unchecked
    }
});

$('form input').on('change', function(evt) {
    //do something
});
```

Comment: Thanks chris. Yes it has jquery added, due my lack of experience in JavaScript and jquery, can you please update your answer with little more details. Hope this won't take alot of time for you.